How to Store llm_client Object in Redis with FastAPI using Pickle or Dill?
I’m working on a FastAPI application where I need to store an Azure OpenAI llm_client object in Redis, along with some session data, and set an expiration time. I initially tried using pickle for serialization but encountered an error. I then attempted to use dill, hoping it would handle the serialization better, but ran into another issue.
Here’s the code I used with pickle:
import redis
import pickle
from openai import AzureOpenAI

# Initialize Redis client
redis_client = redis.Redis(
    host='redis-13661.c212.ap-south-1-1.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com',
    port=13661,
    password="*******",
    username="default"
)

# Initialize llm_client
client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint="https://my-openai-endpoint.azure.com/",
    api_key="*******",
    api_version="2024-02-01"
)

# Store session data in Redis with an expiration time of 1 hour
session_data = {"llm_client": client}
session_id = "1234"
redis_client.hmset(session_id, 3600, pickle.dumps(session_data))

When I run this, I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

I then tried using dill instead of pickle:
import redis
import dill
from openai import AzureOpenAI

# Initialize Redis client
redis_client = redis.Redis(
    host='redis-13661.c212.ap-south-1-1.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com',
    port=13661,
    password="*******",
    username="default"
)

# Initialize llm_client
client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint="https://my-openai-endpoint.azure.com/",
    api_key="*******",
    api_version="2024-02-01"
)

# Store session data in Redis with an expiration time of 1 hour
session_data = {"llm_client": client}
session_id = "1234"
redis_client.hmset(session_id, 3600, dill.dumps(session_data))

However, this also fails with a similar error:
TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object

What I’ve Tried

Using pickle: Results in the _thread.RLock error, likely due to the lock objects in the llm_client.
Using dill: Results in the SSLContext error, which suggests that dill also can’t handle certain objects within llm_client.

My Question

Is there a way to serialize the llm_client object for storage in Redis?
Are there alternative approaches for handling non-pickleable objects in Redis, such as excluding them and reconstructing the object upon retrieval?

Any guidance or suggestions on best practices would be much appreciated.


"Is there a way to serialize the llm_client object for storage in Redis?" No. There should also be no reason to.
